# Chrome extension: chrome.alarms not working after main window closes

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I want to check a certain value in my extension every few hours using the chrome.alarms API. The alarms are triggering while the main window page is open, but when the main window closes the alarms no longer trigger. My event listener and alarm creation are on the background page. In my background.js, I try to make a notification appear at a regular interval to test the alarm.

This is the relevant part of my "background.js":

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(e) {

  chrome.runtime.getBackgroundPage(function(bg) {
      bg.chrome.alarms.create("beep", {delayInMinutes: 1, periodInMinutes: 0.1} );
  });

  var opt = {
    type: "basic",
    title: "Task due",
    message: 'A task is due tomorrow.',
    iconUrl: "chrome-extension://paomcbcgpoikdcjhbanhllhdbemcjokf/Agenda_32.png",
    buttons: [
      {
      title: 'Mark as done'
      }
    ]
  }
  

  function clr() {
    chrome.notifications.clear('tst');
  }
  
  chrome.alarms.onAlarm.addListener(function(alarm) {
    console.log("beeep");
    clr();
    chrome.notifications.create('tst', opt);
  });
});
```

How can I make it so that the alarms trigger even after my main window closes? I have read some documentation on this but the solution to this eludes me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extensions run only when at least one browser window of the user profile is running unless you specifically add a [permission](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/declare_permissions) in manifest.json:

```js
"permissions": ["background"],
"background": {
  "persistent": true,
  "scripts": ["bg.js"]
}
```

> Makes Chrome start up early and and shut down late, so that apps and extensions can have a longer life.

> When any installed hosted app, packaged app, or extension has "background" permission, Chrome runs (invisibly) as soon as the user logs into their computer—before the user launches Chrome. The "background" permission also makes Chrome continue running (even after its last window is closed) until the user explicitly quits Chrome.

#### Important!

Make sure `Continue running background apps` is enabled in Chrome settings:

[image]

Comment: Is this functionality possible without turning on "persistent": true? I read that the best practices use "persistent": false to save memory usage.

Comment: AFAIK only persistent scripts can do it. Whether it's bad or not, depends on how often your extension would wake up otherwise. If it's 1000 times a day then persistent:false would be bad for overall performance and power consumption. This is not mentioned in the documentation because, well, it's a very inconvenient truth.